# try to implode string using php and redis

Tags: php, redis

this is my php file:-

```
    <?php
    require "predis-0.8/autoload.php";
    Predis\Autoloader::register();
    try {
        $redis = new Predis\Client();
        }catch (Exception $e) {
    };
    $redis->del("aaa");
    for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
    {
    $randNo=rand('1','5');
    $ec = $redis->set("arr",$randNo);
    $str = $redis->get("arr").",";
    echo ($str);
    }
    $comma = implode(",", $str);
    echo ($comma);
?>
```

i am using Redis with PHP.
i am try to implode strint.
but its not work.
return me error. `Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed`  
any idea why i fetch this warning.
thanks in advance.

Comment: $str need to be array, its look like a string  $str = $redis->get("arr").","; , also you always overide the same variable $str

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the function `explode` not `implode`.

implode takes an array and concatenates the elements together with the given string in between.

explode takes a string and splits it into an array at the places where it find the given string by removing that string.

```
$arr = array( 'foo', 'bar');
$imp = implode(',', $arr); # $imp == 'foo,bar'
$exp = explode(',', $imp); # $exp == array('foo', 'bar')
```

Edit:

After further reading of your code. I guess you try to store an array within redis.
To achieve that (and even more complex data structures) you need to convert the data into a string. The easiest way to achieve this would be `serialize` and `unserialize`.

```
$data; # contains some data , either array or objects or int or ...
$redis->set('foo', serialize($data));
$other_data = unserialize($redis->get('foo')); # $other_data == $data
```

Answer (score -2):

Hye, i think these two links can help u

1. http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_implode.asp
2. http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp